# Where do I insert the comma?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Where do I place the comma in this sentence?

> I am in the process of renewing my insurance policy however I don't know the correct amount.

Comment: Well, you need some punctuation (comma, semicolon, dash, or period) between "policy" and "however".  And, some would argue, there should be a comma after "however".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a proofreading service or a writers' workshop, though we can help you if you can identify a specific question of grammar or usage. At the minimum where do you think it should go, or not, and which punctuation guides have you consulted thus far? I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 2):

In your sentence you have two separate and independent "phrases" and they should be separated by a semicolon, dash or a period. The first one is the following affirmation:

> I am in the process of renewing my insurance policy.

The second one is started with a introductory clause **however**, so a comma should come after it (as stated in 2 in the reference*):

> However, I don't know the correct amount.

Joining both you can have this final sentence:

> I am in the process of renewing my insurance policy; however, I don't know the correct amount.

- Reference 1: [Purdue OWL - Commas](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/02/)
- Reference 2: [Commas with conjunctive adverbs](http://www.grammarerrors.com/punctuation/commas-with-conjunctive-adverbs-however-furthermore-etc/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not the best at grammar, but I would think it would be either side of 'however'.

> I am in the process of renewing my insurance policy, however, I don't know the correct amount.
>
> I would like to know the cost of processing a new insurance policy.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you could make the assumption that an insurance policy needs to be processed so, you will not need to omit 'process'.

How much will my insurance policy cost to renew?
Simpler.

Comment: You can edit and comment on your existing answers.